# Can we declare a variable in ffmpeg ffprobe

Tags: powershell, variables, ffmpeg, ffprobe

I am new to ffmpeg.

I want to get a video duration through ffmpeg and declare it to a variable. where I can use the value for a different function. I am using power shell.

This is my code:

```
ffmpeg -i 1aef53e6-92ac-4d28-89f8-4cce28fa0f58.mp4 2>&1 | sed -n 's/Duration: \(.*\), start/\1/gp'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided you have set up the path for ffmpeg in the Windows `PATH` variable like explained [here](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/20495/how-do-i-set-up-and-use-ffmpeg-in-windows), this should get you the duration value for the file:

```
$filename = '1aef53e6-92ac-4d28-89f8-4cce28fa0f58.mp4'
$duration = if ((ffmpeg -i $filename 2>&1 | Out-String) -match 'Duration:\s+([\d:.]+)') { $matches[1] }
```

Mind you, after this `$duration` is a string.
If you need to create a `TimeSpan` object of this, use:

```
$t = [TimeSpan]::Parse($duration)
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `ffmpeg` to get the duration: it's output is not meant to be machine parsed and it's messy.

Use `ffprobe`:

```
$duration = ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of csv=p=0 input.mp4
```

- This will give the duration in seconds. If you want HH:MM:SS format add the `-sexagesimal` option.
- No need for any additional processing with `sed`, regex, etc, as `ffprobe` will directly give you the duration and only the duration.
- More info at [FFmpeg Wiki: FFprobe Tips](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/FFprobeTips) and [`ffprobe` documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html).