# ffmpeg - ffprobe duration format change

Tags: powershell, ffmpeg, format, duration, ffprobe

I am using ffmpeg to get some file durations 
Below is my code

```
$filename = '1aef53e6-92ac-4d28-89f8-4cce28fa0f58.mp4'
$duration = if ((ffmpeg -i $filename 2>&1 | Out-String) -match 'Duration:\s+([\d:.]+)') { $matches[1] }
```

Actual output would be like
H :M :S : F
00:00:00.00

I need the output to be like 
00:00:00:00
Between seconds and frame, there is a " . " full stop, I need it to be a " : "

any suggestions ?

Comment: Use ffprobe, not ffmpeg. The output from ffmpeg is not meant to be machine parsed. See my answer in your previous question: [Can we declare a variable in ffmpeg ffprobe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61214311/), then use the Windows equivalent of `sed` to change the `.` to `:`, (alternatively output the duration in seconds).

Comment: @llogan thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Add `.Replace(".",":")` after `$matches[1]`

`$duration = if ((ffmpeg -i $filename 2>&1 | Out-String) -match 'Duration:\s+([\d:.]+)') { $matches[1].Replace(".",":") }`